# How are words in Korean alphabetized/sorted?

Tags: orthography

[This was one of our definition questions.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language/74237#74237) How are things like dictionaries sorted, and what is equivalent to our A-Z or Z-A lists?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dictionary order is defined in [한글맞춤법 2장 4항](https://www.law.go.kr/%ED%96%89%EC%A0%95%EA%B7%9C%EC%B9%99/%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80%EB%A7%9E%EC%B6%A4%EB%B2%95)

- 자음(19자) ㄱ ㄲ ㄴ ㄷ ㄸ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅃ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅉ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ
- 모음(21자) ㅏ ㅐ ㅑ ㅒ ㅓ ㅔ ㅕ ㅖ ㅗ ㅘ ㅙ ㅚ ㅛ ㅜ ㅝ ㅞ ㅟ ㅠ ㅡ ㅢ ㅣ
- 받침(27자) ㄱ ㄲ ㄳ ㄴ ㄵ ㄶ ㄷ ㄹ ㄺ ㄻ ㄼ ㄽ ㄾ ㄿ ㅀ ㅁ ㅂ ㅄ
  ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ

A typical way of memorizing these is to say '가나다라마바사아자차카타파하', '아야어여오요우유으이', then insert the appropriate double alphabets in between. As for the 받침, the order is more or less random, and only for consistency across dictionaries. I don't think a normal Korean speaker would know it (I had to look it up too).

As @Leftium pointed out, this order is the one used in South Korea. For historical and North Korean ordering see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#Sorting_order.

Comment: Note the current sorting order is relatively recent, and North Korea uses a slightly different order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#Sorting_order

Comment: @Leftium good point. I didn't know that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: How do I interpret this? Does it mean you read the 3 rows from left-right top-bottom? Or are they interwoven somehow? Is the final sort order ㄱ ㄲ ㄴ ㄷ ㄸ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅃ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅉ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ ㅏ ㅐ ㅑ ㅒ ㅓ ㅔ ㅕ ㅖ ㅗ ㅘ ㅙ ㅚ ㅛ ㅜ ㅝ ㅞ ㅟ ㅠ ㅡ ㅢ ㅣ ㄱ ㄲ ㄳ ㄴ ㄵ ㄶ ㄷ ㄹ ㄺ ㄻ ㄼ ㄽ ㄾ ㄿ ㅀ ㅁ ㅂ ㅄ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ?

Comment: Also link is broken.