# What numbers are associated with base Korean characters?

Tags: numbers, character-meanings

Given the [sort order of Korean characters](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-are-words-in-korean-alphabetized-sorted), are they given numbers 1-x? If not, are there any contexts where these base characters are given numbers? I am specifically thinking about [Gematria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria), but it doesn't have to be specifically for gematria but can be for mathematical purposes, or just purely for sorting purposes, mapping them to a sequence of integers.

Specifically only talking about these:

- 자음(19자) ㄱ ㄲ ㄴ ㄷ ㄸ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅃ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅉ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ
- 모음(21자) ㅏ ㅐ ㅑ ㅒ ㅓ ㅔ ㅕ ㅖ ㅗ ㅘ ㅙ ㅚ ㅛ ㅜ ㅝ ㅞ ㅟ ㅠ ㅡ ㅢ ㅣ
- 받침(27자) ㄱ ㄲ ㄳ ㄴ ㄵ ㄶ ㄷ ㄹ ㄺ ㄻ ㄼ ㄽ ㄾ ㄿ ㅀ ㅁ ㅂ ㅄ ㅅ ㅆ ㅇ ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ ㅎ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes they use “가나다라마바사아자차카타파하/ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ” **for ordinals** (for ordering purposes), just like how Latin’s “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz” is used, but the characters themselves **don’t have numeral, arithmetic meanings.**